# Подключение модулей Python по условию

Tags: python

Как правильно организовать импорт модулей.
Например, если значения переменной true, то использовать модуль module1, если false, то - module2.
импорт всех модулей на начале, импортирует лишний модуль.
Но как тогда импортировать только нужный модуль?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень просто.

```
CONST = True

if CONST:
    import module1 as module
else:
    import module2 as module
```

Теперь под общим названием `module` лежит один из модулей, в зависимости от того, True CONST или False.

Comment: Просто слегка дополню ответ:
В исходниках часто можно встретить такой код:

    try:
        from thread import _local as local
    except ImportError:
        from _threading_local import local

И это абсолютно нормально, ImportError в частности для того и существует. try-except или импорт по условию - это необычно, но вполне допустимо, стиль написания кода не должен ограничивать логику программы.

Comment: Так тут другая ситуация. Второй модуль импортируется, если при импорте первого пойдёт что-то не так. Тут человек хочет чтобы ему рассказали про простейший if.